# join 2 spatiallines in one SpatiallineDataframe in r

Tags: r

I have created **2 spatialLines** using the function gdistance::shortestpath. I would like to merge them into single SLDF, but keeping the id of both spatiallines .The **desired output will be a 1 SLDF and 2 features**!! I am sure that there should be simple way how to complete that in R, but I can't find how. 
My 2 SpatialLines:

```
mergedSpatialLines
#class       : SpatialLines 
#features    : 1 
#extent      : 421965.7, 480965.7, 791904.1, 863268.1  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#coord. ref. : +proj=laea +lat_0=30 +lon_0=-30 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +a=6370997 +b=6370997 +units=m +no_defs 
mergedSpatialLine2815
#class       : SpatialLines 
#features    : 1 
#extent      : 466965.7, 482965.7, 823204.1, 833846.1  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#coord. ref. : +proj=laea +lat_0=30 +lon_0=-30 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +a=6370997 +b=6370997 +units=m +no_defs 

unidos<-gUnion(mergedSpatialLine,mergedSpatialLine2815)
unidos
#class       : SpatialLines 
#features    : 1 
#extent      : 421965.7, 482965.7, 791904.1, 863268.1  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#coord. ref. : +proj=laea +lat_0=30 +lon_0=-30 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +a=6370997 +b=6370997 +units=m +no_defs
```

Comment: Please, provide a reproducible example.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BwqSBe1Yq-FBenlQSVFYYkVwbzg

Comment: I changed the names of the spatial lines data frame in the drive link, this files are called there spldf and spldf2.

Comment: The merge between these both files is possible in ArcGis, with merge tools. But I don't know what can I use in R. Any idea?

Comment: The idea is combines multiple input datasets of the same data type into a single, new output dataset in r

Comment: I found my solution...it's simple:  mydata <- rbind(splndf, splndf3)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found the answer to this question anywhere else and Marta's solution works beautifully but was hidden in the comments above (at the bottom) so I almost missed it.

You can rbind SpatialLines which I did not know before (thanks Marta!)

Copying Marta's solution from above:

```
mydata <- rbind(spatiallines1, spatiallines2)
```